# Soap on HTTPS Apache CFX with user certificate authentication not working

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, soap

We have a server running on Tomcat. This server connects to several third part services.

I developed and tested the connection to a SOAP service. This service requires the client to identify using a certificate. The first version set the properties:

- javax.net.ssl.trustStore
- javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
- javax.net.ssl.keyStore
- javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
- javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType

My code worked when tested alone, but when my code was integrated to our server, it messed up the connection to other third part servers. Looking for a solution to this problem, I found *Apache CFX*. I noted that this library has an API to set the certificates without the need to change global properties. We don´t use Spring and I would like to configure by code, but I am getting exceptions.

**Code**

```
  public NotaFiscalServiceSoap getNotaFiscalServiceSoap() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    if(notaFiscalServiceSoap==null){
      JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean() ;           
      factory.setWsdlURL(municipio.getUrlWsdl().toString());
      factory.setServiceClass(NotaFiscalServiceSoap.class);
      factory.setServiceName(Q_NAME);
      factory.setConduitSelector(getConduitSelector()); 
      notaFiscalServiceSoap = factory.create(NotaFiscalServiceSoap.class);
    }

    return notaFiscalServiceSoap;

  }

  private ConduitSelector getConduitSelector() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {


    ServiceInfo serviceInfo = new ServiceInfo();
    serviceInfo.setTargetNamespace(NAMESPACE);

    EndpointInfo endpointInfo = new EndpointInfo();
    endpointInfo.setService(serviceInfo);
    endpointInfo.setName(Q_NAME);
    endpointInfo.setAddress(municipio.getUrlWsdl().toString());

    URLConnectionHTTPConduit conduit = new URLConnectionHTTPConduit(null, endpointInfo);
    conduit.setTlsClientParameters(getTLSClientParameters());
    ConduitSelector selector = new UpfrontConduitSelector(conduit);
    return selector;
  }


  private TLSClientParameters getTLSClientParameters() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException{
    KeyStoreType trustKeyStore = new KeyStoreType();
    trustKeyStore.setFile(pathCertWsdl);
    trustKeyStore.setPassword(passCertWsdl);
    trustKeyStore.setType("jks");

    TrustManagersType trustManagerType = new TrustManagersType();  
    trustManagerType.setKeyStore(trustKeyStore); 

    KeyStoreType keyStoreType = new KeyStoreType();
    keyStoreType.setFile(pathCertA1);
    keyStoreType.setPassword(passCertA1);
    keyStoreType.setType("pkcs12");

    KeyManagersType keyManagerType = new KeyManagersType();   
    keyManagerType.setKeyStore(keyStoreType);
    keyManagerType.setKeyPassword(passCertA1);

    TLSClientParametersType clientParametersType = new TLSClientParametersType();
    clientParametersType.setTrustManagers(trustManagerType);
    clientParametersType.setKeyManagers(keyManagerType);
    clientParametersType.setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultHostnameVerifier(true);
    clientParametersType.setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory(true);

    return TLSClientParametersConfig.createTLSClientParametersFromType(clientParametersType);
  }
```

**Exception**

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password must not be null
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:132)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:96)
    ...
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:394)
    ...
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://issonline.vilavelha.es.gov.br/SistemaIss/WebService/NotaFiscalService.asmx?WSDL'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2390)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2422)
    ...  
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    ... 
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    ... 
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

I used this URL as reference: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=support-examples-master/jaxws/cxfSsl.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/redhat/gss/jaxws/TestClient.java

1. I changed the way the soap service object was created. That way I could get the HTTPConduit and configure it, instead of having to create many auxiliary objects (probably I made a few mistakes here).
2. I created the keystores instead of configuring the certificates.

Comment: That link is broken - "Please use the search portal to find the examples".